# Bind MediaTomb to one interface

Tags: 10.04, server, interface, mediatomb

I hava a Ubuntu Server (10.04 LST) running MediaTomb. The server is also a gateway to the network, so I want MediaTomb only to listen on one interface. In the MediaTomb config file `etc/mediatomb/config.xml` I already set `<interface>eth2</interface>`, but MediaTomb is still available on the other interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Edit /etc/default/mediatomb then restart server.

Comment: It would be very useful if you can expand your answer for a step by step explanation.  thanks.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  To remove the negative reputation points, [edit] your answer, improve it, and drop a note so that I can review my assessment of your answer.  Alternatively, [delete] it altogether and the negative reputation points will be reversed automatically by the system. (I do this too for answers that give me negative reputation points) **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

start meditomb with

```
mediatomb -e wlan0
```